# First time using jQuery, something its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to do a website that reads images from a file and then change background from that images.

To do that, I wanna use a jQuery named bgswitcher:
https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher
http://rewish.github.io/jquery-bgswitcher/

But It's not working, it's my first time with jQuery, so of course I'm doing some kind of stupid error. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $dir = "img/";
    $numFiles = 0;
    $fh = fopen('config.txt','r');
    $imgTime = fgets($fh);
    $transTime = fgets($fh);

    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            $file = readdir($dh);$file = readdir($dh); //Para deshacerme del . i ..
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                $files[] = $file;
                $numFiles++;
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Gestor Publicitari v0.2</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color:white;
            }       
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            var images = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
            var numImg = <?php echo json_encode($numFiles); ?>;
            var imgTime = parseInt(<?php echo json_encode($imgTime); ?>)*1000;

            $('.box').bgswitcher({
                images: ["img/1.jpg","img/2.jpg","img/3.jpg","img/4.jpg","img/5.jpg"],
                effect: "fade",
                interval: 500;
            });
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <p>TEST</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To discard errors, I'm not using readed files, I'm using 5 example images that exists.

Comment: you have not included the plugin files

Comment: you have to download and include the plugin file - http://rewish.github.io/jquery-bgswitcher/jquery.bgswitcher.js

Comment: When it comes mostly like a client side issue, you might just give your generated `html` and try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as @Arun suggestion, you need to include `bgswitcher` plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-bgSwitcher.js"></script>
```

After that, since you're placing your `<script>` in the `<head>` section then you need to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function(){...})` or shorter form `$(function(){...});` to make sure your DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var images = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
    var numImg = <?php echo json_encode($numFiles); ?>;
    var imgTime = parseInt(<?php echo json_encode($imgTime); ?>)*1000;

    $('.box').bgswitcher({
        images: ["img/1.jpg","img/2.jpg","img/3.jpg","img/4.jpg","img/5.jpg"],
        effect: "fade",
        interval: 500;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I also like to use `$(document).ready(function(){...});` as it speak for itself

Comment: Nice'n complete answer. +1

Comment: thanks you so much, now it's perfectly working and understanding jquery a little more!!
Ah, and its jquery.bgSwitcher.js, not jquery-bgSwitcher.js!!

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside jquery ready function

```
$(function(){
   // your code
});
```